flyway docker image vs community edition
I'm looking into using Flyway as a schema migration tool for a Google BigQuery database. I see on the BigQuery page that there's a limitation on the size of the data (if I'm reading this right):

Flyway Community Edition has a 10GB data limit across all datasets, and this is unlimited in Flyway Teams

My question is, if I plan on using the open source docker image (flyway/flyway vs Redgate/flyway) does this limitation still apply?

I guess judging by this code https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/a66a1a37f9c1b1d9ef8fd7fb2137ff2678d4779b/flyway-database/flyway-gcp-bigquery/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/database/bigquery/BigQueryDatabase.java#L61 it does affect it
